# How to prevent Sequelize from converting Date object to local time

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, utc

I am using [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) for a node project. It's connecting to a Postgres databsae, which contains a table with a `DATE` field (unlike `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`, `DATE` has not time data).

In the code I'm modeling the date using a javascript `Date` object, which stores the time as UTC midnight. When I use that to insert a record into the table using that `Date` object, sequelize is apparently coverting it to local time first because the records are always 1 day behind. So if I want to insert 2000-10-31 into the database I end up with 2000-10-30. I am in UTC-5.

How do I tell sequelize to not convert the Date to a local time before inserting into the database?

Here is some sample code. I also created a [repository](https://github.com/dland512/sequelize-date-issue) if you want to run it yourself.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('testdb', 'postgres', '???', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres'
});

TestTable = sequelize.define('date_test',
    {
        id: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true
        },

        someDate: {
            field: 'some_date',
            type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    }
);

// midnight UTC on Halloween 
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2000, 9, 31));

// converts to local time resulting in 2000-10-30
TestTable.create({ someDate: date })
    .then(function() {
        // also apparently converts to local time resulting in 2000-10-30
        return TestTable.create({ someDate: date.toUTCString() });
    })
    .then(function() {
        // convert to string, definitely works but seems unnecessary
        var strDate = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + pad2(date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad2(date.getUTCDate());
        return TestTable.create({ someDate: strDate });
    })
    .then(function() {
        // cerate a new local Date, also works but seems hacky
        var newDate = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate());
        return TestTable.create({ someDate: newDate });
    })
    .then(function() {
        process.exit(0);
    });


function pad2(n) {
    if (n.length === 1) {
        return '0' + n;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the date is created as UTC time, but because `DATEONLY` has no awareness of the timezone, it formats the Date object  "as is" (in local time) with format `YYYY-MM-DD` (using moment.js - [see here in source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/bce3d9aa61c8ca19a5d61af67993038628d5f8f8/lib/data-types.js#L430)).

For a `DATEONLY` you can just do this:

```
var date = new Date(2000, 9, 31);
```

That will insert the date correctly.

Programmers seldom say this, but for once you were thinking *too much* about timezones!

---

### OLD INCORRECT ANSWER

It depends on how you are checking the value, but javascript and postgresql are converting it to your local timezone for display.

Sequelize uses a **TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE** type for a date field ([source](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#data-types)).

In the [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) it says:

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's timezone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.
>
> When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone. To see the time in another time zone, either change timezone or use the AT TIME ZONE construct (see Section 9.9.3).

If you are outputting the time value in postgresql, try converting it to UTC. If you are are outputting it in javascript, try `date.toUTCString()`.

The reason your hacks appear to work is because they are actually storing `2000-11-01 05:00` but when you inspect the value, it is converted into your local time zone.

Comment: Sequelize is not creating the date field as type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` because I'm not using the `Sequelize.DATE` type. I'm using `Sequelize.DATEONLY`, which creates a postgres `DATE` field, which has no time data.

Comment: How are you inspecting the value of the table? In postgresql or javascript?

Comment: I'm looking at them in postgres

Comment: If you run `SELECT your_date_field AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' FROM your_table` does it show the correct date? Sorry, I don't have a postgresql installation handy...

Comment: It shows `2018-10-31 05:00:00` which is the correct date, but is the time meaningful since postgres doesn't store time values in DATE fields? It looks like it's assuming it's midnight my time (UTC-5) and then converting it to UTC by adding 5 hours.

Comment: I see, so sequelize is using moment to convert my UTC time to a local time, which is rolling it back to the previous day because of my timezone. So I guess the proper fix would be to create a local `Date` object using the values from the UTC `Date` object? Like this: `var localDate = new Date(utcDate.getUTCFullYear(), utcDate.getUTCMonth(), utcDate.getUTCDate())`? That should create a local `Date` object set to midnight on the date I want.

Comment: Since the `DATEONLY` sequelize field doesn't care about timezone, I would skip the UTC part and just create your date like this: `var date = new Date(2000, 9, 31);`

Comment: But I have to know which values to pass into the `Date` constructor and those are coming from other `Date` objects whose time values are midnight UTC.

Comment: Apologies, yes I can't see any cleaner way to do it. If you store the dates as midnight local time, you can just pass those straight in. But if you are getting them in UTC time for whatever reason, you will have to use the `utcDate.getUTC...()` functions - or you could add the local time offset to the UTC date, but that seems equally hacky.